# How to SELECT SQL data using the results from a previous SELECT

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Lets guess I have 3 tables:

Table a where I have a name and email

Table b where I have a text and user (as a reference to email from table a)

Table c where I have follower and following (both references to email in table a)

Im trying to develop a simple html/php/sql web that allows me to register many users and let them post different texts while also having the chance to follow or be followed by other users (already done) and I want to give an user the possibility to display the texts from table b that he himself posted and those from the users he is following

Im seriously struggling with how to extract this information

```
SELECT b.text
  FROM tableB as b
 LEFT JOIN tableC as c
    ON b.user = c.follower
 WHERE b.user = "currentuser"
```

This is as far as I got, which only shows the texts posted by the user himself (something I can do way more simple) but I cant seem to understand how to get those from the users he is following

I hope its understandable without any photo

Comment: If you can, Download Oracle MySQL Workbench, it will allow you to do some things much easier.  I have a thing I built similar to this, but instead of joining them all together, one select shows them their things, and then I move to the next recordset in the stored procedure and do the other select, that way you can sort of sort the two into different areas, unless you just for some reason want to combine them all into one, but seems like it might create some confusion for the user.  Also see this link if you are went on using a JOIN https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: `hat he himself posted and those from the users he is following` both at once?  or you mean just one or the other?

Comment: I would want both results together yes, both his own texts, and the texts from the users he follows

Comment: I hope you aren't really using a,b,c as aliases; if you are, I'm not surprised you are finding this difficult.  descriptive names for things help.

Comment: Instead of using email as a  key, use auto_increment id from tableA. This way when user changes his/her email address, you need to update it only in tableA.

Comment: email was the key cause its UNIQUE and cant be changed no matter what by the task's nature, thats why I did it, but thanks for the idea for next projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first want to find all following users in table c rows where the current user is the follower.  Then you want to add the current user (or alternatively always have all users follow themselves).  Then you want to find all texts for those users.

So:

```
select b.text
from (
    select following as user
    from tableC
    where follower="current user"
    union
    select "current user"
) show_users
join tableB as b on b.user=show_users.user
```

or if you have a tableC row where follower=following for all users, just:

```
select b.text
from tableC as c
join tableB as b on b.user=c.following
where c.follower="current user"
```

Comment: This is the answer, I liked the idea of making an user follow himself as soon as the account is registered and it works perfectly fine, and adding a "date" for when a text is registered allows me to order them, thank you so much